is real-time video compression possible on a Raspberry Pi to wirelessly transmit multiple live feeds?
the idea I want to achieve is this: I'm planning to make an eye-tracker device, which is in 2 parts: the first part is what the subject/user wears, includes an eyeglass-shaped frame, 2 Infrared cameras and one RGB camera, which are going to be connected to a Raspberry Pi powered by a battery pack. and the feeds are going to be transmitted to the second part, which is a wifi receiver connected to a pc.
so the 3 live video feeds are this: 2 grayscale feeds and 1 RGB feed, and let's assume they're in 720p-120fps.
the question is, can I use FFmpeg, to compress the feeds in realtime, and make the packages small enough so they fit the bandwidth that the WiFi 5 module onboard the Pi (or an external wifi 6 module) can provide?
I want the compression to be nearly lossless, but it's ok if it's not absolutely perfect. is it possible? and if so, which codec I should use and what settings you suggest me to use?
Edit 1:

1 * 1280×720@120fps 24-Bit (RGB) = 2,654,208 kbps ~= 2.65 Gbps
2 * 1280×720@120fps 8-Bit (Grayscale) = 1,769,472 kbps ~= 1.77 Gbps total
raw bandwidth needed: ~4.42 Gbps

Intel® Wi-Fi 7 BE200 can go up to 5.8 Gbps, what if I use this with a Pi 5?

Does your Pi model have any built-in hardware codecs (the way PC GPUs often do)? At the specified parameters, CPU-based encoding seems to be out of the question.

@DrMoishe Pippik, interesting, well 3Pi's would be too big and heavy for the user to wear, do you suggest any alternatives? can Pi-5's built-in wifi module handle the 3 feeds wirelessly without or with light compression? or maybe with a wifi 6 module added on top?

If you make the calculations, uncompressed RGB 720p @ 120 fps is 2.5 Gbps per feed, so I'm having my doubts.

See here for hardware codec https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/148525/43814
